# Automatically scroll to anchor at end of animation

Tags: javascript, animation, adobe-edge, muse

I've created an 8 second animation (.oam) in **Edge Animate** for a website made with **Adobe Muse**. When the animation finishes I want the page to automatically scroll down to an anchor I've placed like it would if I clicked an object with a hyperlink.

I've inserted a Trigger @ 8000 ms with the following code;

`window.open("#about", "_parent")`

When I preview my website the animation works perfectly but at the end of the 8 seconds instead of scrolling down to the anchor, it reloads the entire page at the anchor instead.

What is the correct code for the trigger?

Thanks

Comment: or is there some code I can add to the <head> in Muse which recognises the animation is finished and and auto scrolls to anchor?

Answer (score 0):

did you try this ?

```
window.location.hash = "#about";
```

Comment: Yes I tried that and when I preview the animation in browser it works. But as soon as I place it in Muse as a .oam file its does absolutely nothing.